# Using the Apple Battery Charger with non-Apple batteries

Tags: battery, charging

The [Apple Battery Charger](http://www.apple.com/battery-charger/)'s product description page states:

> The Apple Battery Charger can recharge one or two batteries at a time. It's optimized for Apple-supplied batteries and it works with AA NiMH batteries from other companies, too.

Does anyone know the required specifications for using non-Apple batteries?

The Apple supplied batteries are AA Ni-MH Min. 1900 mAh 1.2V HR6.

I have some Powerex AA Ni-MH Min. 2500 mAh 1.2V, so I'm wondering if they are compatible. I'm also curious what other non-Apple batteries are compatible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Apple Batteries are Rebranded Sanyo Batteries

According to [engadget](http://www.engadget.com/2010/08/12/apples-rechargeable-aa-batteries-are-rebranded-sanyo-eneloops/), the Apple supplied batteries are actually [Sanyo Eneloop HR-3UTG](http://www.engadget.com/2009/10/06/sanyo-eneloop-batteries-good-for-1-500-recharges-maintain-70-c/), so it appears that's one option for buying additional batteries to use with the Apple Battery Charger.

### Powerex Batteries Don't Work

According to the [Apple Battery Charger Manual](http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/Battery_Charger_UG.pdf),

> - Flashing Amber: May indicate any of the following conditions:
>
>   - The batteries haven’t been properly installed in the charger.
>   - An unsupported type of battery is in the charger.
>   - The batteries may be faulty or damaged and should be replaced.

With that information, I tried charging the Powerex 2500 and 2700 batteries but received a flashing amber light.

Looks like I need to buy some of the [Sanyo Eneloop HR-3UTG](http://www.engadget.com/2009/10/06/sanyo-eneloop-batteries-good-for-1-500-recharges-maintain-70-c/) batteries.

Comment: Well, I sometimes get flashing amber with the Apple-supplied batteries.  If so, I take them out and carefully reinsert them, then charging begins.  So perhaps make no conclusion about other batteries based on a single try.

Comment: @GEdgar: I also get the flashing amber sometimes with the Apple supplied batteries, so I did remove and reinsert to make sure that it wasn't a fluke.

Answer (score 2):

I too had original apple batteries and the orange light was flashing.  I took carefully reinserted (rotated and cleaned the bottom and top of the leads) them and they seem to be charging now.

Answer (score 2):

And in my case, cleaning the terminals on the Apple charger made all the difference